# print the array keys and values in a row

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$data = array(
array(
    'Name' => 'Trixie',
    'Color' => 'Green',
    'Element' => 'Earth',
    'Likes' => 'Flowers'
    ),
array(
    'Name' => 'Tinkerbell',
    'Element' => 'Air',
    'Likes' => 'Singning',
    'Color' => 'Blue'
    ),  
array(
    'Element' => 'Water',
    'Likes' => 'Dancing',
    'Name' => 'Blum',
    'Color' => 'Pink'
    ),
 );
```

I need to print out the data like this:

```
| Name         |  color       |   Element      |  Likes     |

 Trixie           Green           Earth           Flowers

 Tinkerball       Blue            Air             Singing

 Blum             Pink            Water           Dancing
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Have you even tried something ?

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: i need to print the above array as in the table format....i have tried but i did'nt get

Comment: Show us the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the type of this question is please write code for me.

Comment: i have tried but i am getting total irrelevent....i think the logic i went wrong please help with your code

Comment: At the very least please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Trixie',
        'Color' => 'Green',
        'Element' => 'Earth',
        'Likes' => 'Flowers'
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'Tinkerbell',
        'Element' => 'Air',
        'Likes' => 'Singning',
        'Color' => 'Blue'
    ),  
    array(
        'Element' => 'Water',
        'Likes' => 'Dancing',
        'Name' => 'Blum',
        'Color' => 'Pink'
    ),
);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Likes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $value): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value['Name'];?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $value['Color'];?></td>     
                <td><?php echo $value['Element'];?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $value['Likes'];?></td> 
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make loop easy

```
echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Color</td><td>Element</td><td>Likes</td></tr>\n";
foreach($data as $row) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr><td>$Name</td><td>$Color</td><td>$Element/td><td>$Likes</td></tr>\n";
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my code

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Color</td>
        <td>Element</td>
        <td>Likes</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' , $value['Name'] , '</td>';
        echo '<td>' , $value['Color'] , '</td>';
        echo '<td>' , $value['Element'] , '</td>';
        echo '<td>' , $value['Likes'] , '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code sample is quite quick n dirty but generates a HTML-Table based on your array

```
  $data = array(
  array(
      'Name' => 'Trixie',
      'Color' => 'Green',
      'Element' => 'Earth',
      'Likes' => 'Flowers'
      ),
  array(
      'Name' => 'Tinkerbell',
      'Element' => 'Air',
      'Likes' => 'Singning',
      'Color' => 'Blue'
      ),  
  array(
      'Element' => 'Water',
      'Likes' => 'Dancing',
      'Name' => 'Blum',
      'Color' => 'Pink'
      ),
   );


  echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Color</td><td>Element</td><td>Likes</td></tr>";

  foreach($data as $key => $row) {

    $name = $row['Name'];
    $color = $row['Color'];
    $element = $row['Element'];
    $likes = $row['Likes'];


    echo sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $name, $color, $element, $likes);

  } 

  echo "</table>";
```